# sql modifying entries by adding a space

Tags: sql

I just ran this command  `update table set mydata = '$' + mydata where [mydata] not like '$%'`
 which worked well, but I forgot to include the space.

so now I have `$123` and `$ 123` how can I add the space to all entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL SERVER you can

```
Update
   table 
Set
   mydata = '$ ' + Right(mydata, Len(mydata)-1)
Where
   mydata Not Like '$ %'
```

Comment: you need the wildcard in the '$ %'